# IOS Xcode 5, How to have all mandatory methods for a Protocol automatically generated

Tags: ios, protocols, xcode5

So for example I create implement a protocol for my class

then in my implementation file I realise I can type

```
"-" and "esc"
```

To get a list of methods.

But is there not an easier way like in Eclipse java to just tell Xcode to create all of the "mandatory" methods for that Protocol for me ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you filed a feature request with Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly like eclipse. You can open the delegate with Command + click on the name of the delegate, and you'll see the list of methods, you can copy them from there.

Comment: thanks thats just as good ! And being new to xocde did not realise that CMD + click takes you to the definition of the object.